# How do you write a unit test for RxJS Angular bufferTime operator?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, rxjs

I have a simple subscription to a Subject with bufferTime:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, Observable, of, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { bufferTime, concatMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AService {
    private someSubject$ = new Subject<boolean>();
    private someObservable$ = this.someSubject$.asObservable();
    private sub: Subscription;

    constructor() {
        this.setupObservables();
    }

    nextSomeSubject() {
        this.someSubject$.next(true);
    }

    private setupObservables() {
        if (this.sub && !this.sub.closed) {
            this.sub.unsubscribe();
        }

        this.sub = this.someObservable$
            .pipe(
                bufferTime(333),
                concatMap(requests => this.doSomething$(requests))
            )
            .subscribe();
    }

    private doSomething$(requests): Observable<unknown> {
        return of(true);
    }
}
```

And my application is doing exactly what I expect. It calls doSomething every 333 millis (as long as there is something in the buffer. I have a filter I'm not showing.)

But I can't figure out how to get the unit test to trigger this without re-calling a function that the constructor of the service already called.

```js
import { discardPeriodicTasks, fakeAsync, TestBed, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AService } from './service';

describe('', () => {
    let service: AService;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({});
        service = TestBed.inject(AService);
    });

    fit('should trigger in 333 millis', fakeAsync(() => {
        const doSomethingSpy = spyOn(service, <any>'doSomething$').and.callThrough();

        // Even though this function is called by the constructor,
        // and executes before you get here in the test if you console.log it,
        // the unit test fails if you don't call this directly?!
        service['setupObservables']();

        service.nextSomeSubject();
        tick(333);
        expect(doSomethingSpy).toHaveBeenCalled(); // failure
        discardPeriodicTasks();
    }));
});
```

Comment: Your test not failing, it throws error.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov this is pseudo-code to represent the situation. It's not executable as is. My running code is not erring anywhere.

Comment: 99% that means that your pseudocode does not represent your problem. And 1% that its some version/environment related problem, cause simple test with bufferTime wokrs fine.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov you're right. The problem is that something is different about the test env that the setup in the constructor doesn't stick. I have to call the method explicitly that sets up this observable AFTER TestBed setup even though the constructor executes. I'll modify my psuedo-code